# Почему-то не могу получить Identity после вставки записи

Tags: c#, sql-server

Вот такой код:

```
public void Save(DataTable save)
{
    using var conn = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString);
    using var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(GetSelectCommand(), conn));
    var commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
    dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
    dataAdapter.RowUpdated += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.StatementType != StatementType.Insert) return;
        OleDbCommand cmd = new(_identityQueryRepository.GetQuery(_dictionarySettings.ConnectionSettings.DbKind), e.Command.Connection);
        e.Row[_dictionarySettings.KeyColumnName] = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    };
    dataAdapter.Update(save);
}

   public class IdentityQueryRepository: IIdentityQueryRepository
    {
        public string GetQuery(DbKind dbKind)
        {
            if (dbKind == DbKind.MSAccess)
                return "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
            if (dbKind == DbKind.MSSQL)
                return "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            throw new NotImplementedException("Данная БД не поддерживается");
        }
    }
```

По идее, я должен получить Identity после вставки, но получаю null...

Работаю в данном случае с SQL Server.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() - Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column **in the same scope**. Функция отработает только если находится в той же процедуре, триггере или пакете. Следующий запрос уже не сможет получить значение

Comment: А почему она норм отрабатывается в MSSMS? Даже если сделать несколько разных запросов в рамках одной вкладки(соединении) не подряд, а сначала один выделить и выполнить, а потом другой.

Comment: Как идея, может этот SSMS оболочку пошерстить решарпером и найти как оно все эти данные получает. По идее откуда-то SSMS берёт эту инфу. Откуда - пока не искал.

Comment: @nick_n_a что-то мне подсказывает, что там много обфускации...

Comment: С автоинкрементом в MSSQL не всё так просто, если мой ответ всёравно вам не помог, пишите, я подскажу что может быть не так. Только что вспомнил, что попытка вставить новое поле - в MSSQL может давать ошибку (в MySQL можно, в MSSQL - нет, msaccess - не знаю), поэтому `GetInsertCommand()` должно генерировать insert без поля, которое автоинкрементное. Может я ещё чего-то не учел, вроде должно работать.

Answer (score 2):

Я попробовал - у меня не с первого раза получилось, но получилось.
Жаль что вы не привели самодостаточный код, надо хорошо угадать что написать что бы выполнилась вставка.

Ваш код надо поменять совсем чуть-чуть. Секрет в том, что надо использовать текущую команду. Где её найти? В аргументах. Команда должна остаться та же

```
public void Save(DataTable save)
{
    using var conn = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString);
    using var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(GetSelectCommand(), conn));
    var commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
    dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
    dataAdapter.RowUpdated += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.StatementType != StatementType.Insert) return;
         // меняем тут ***********
         e.Command.CommandText =_identityQueryRepository.GetQuery(_dictionarySettings.ConnectionSettings.DbKind);
        // И тут
        e.Row[_dictionarySettings.KeyColumnName] = Convert(e.Command.ExecuteScalar()).ToInt32();
    };
    dataAdapter.Update(save);
}
```

И ещё маленькое но. Мелкософту не нравится почему то int32, он зачем-то в int32 засовывает decimal (у меня в int поле всунул), - лучше делать через `Convert.ToInt32`, потому что прямой каст может дать ошибку.

Касательно  MSSMS - можно легко убедится что он не закрывает команду в рамках одной вкладке выполнив `select @@spid;`. Не запрещено не закрывать команду. (Хотя возможно он хранит не команду а сессию или как то ещё) В singlethread если закрыть команду и открыть новую - из пула подтянется старая, но из-за DataAdapter - этого у вас не произошло. После spid можете так же посмотреть в "зеркало" так

```
select  cast(replace(replace(replace((select  text from  sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle)),'&','&amp;')  ,'<','&lt;') ,'>','&gt;') as xml)   sql_text,
 * from sys.dm_exec_requests r with(nolock) where sql_handle is not null
```

`

P.S. Так же понравилась ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row по ней можно почитать какую инфу можно с базы по автогенераторам вытрусить.

Ну и приведу недостающий код (больше времени на это потратил чем на придумать ответ)

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString);
var command = new OleDbCommand("select * from my_table");
var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { null }); // По числу столбцов, один создал для теста
Save(dt);
```